# Deleted /opt directory from linux machine , will there be any reboot problem for machine?

Tags: linux

I deleted `/opt` directory from my Linux machine , will there be any reboot problem for machine?

Comment: Which distribution?

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be.  /opt should not contain any vital system software, but optional software.  As long as you didn't wipe out /usr/bin, or /usr/sbin, you should be okay.  Of course, this may vary by distribution.

Comment: Although if you have added any executables or data from /opt to the startup scripts there could be errors in the scripts but it should still boot.

Answer (score 0):

/opt, traditionally, is defined by the file system hierarchy standard as for 'optional application suite software' back then staroffice used it for installation of software, and usually these software are installed by the user, not bundled in the distribution of linux.

Thus, if you know that there is nothing inside, you can safely delete it. this should not create problem during rebooting as it is really unusual for the init scripts to touch on /opt.